# How do I check that a session object contains a particular key/value entry

Tags: java, jsp, session

I want to check if a certain key/value pair has been set.

How do I check if a an entry with key named "keyName" exists. Sample code or a pointer to an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to differ between "not set" and `null`, step through `session.getAttributeNames()` and search your key name.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a simple introductory tutorial to [JSP Sessions](http://www.jsptut.com/Sessions.jsp)

In essence you should just need to check that `session.getAttribute("keyName")` is not null.

Comment: How do you recognize whether you set keyName to null, or it's not set at all?

Comment: I would imagine that it would no doubt contain some form of data if it was set.